# Duplicate image finder with folder options

Tags: windows, gratis, images, offline, duplicate-files

I am looking for a duplicate file finder that I can use to easily remove all the duplicates from a folder location - for example if it finds a duplicate that exists in folders A and B as well, have an option for mass deleting from folder B. I would prefer it also have options for always deleting a lower-quality image of the same picture (i.e. a cropped version or a thumbnail)

I would prefer a FLOSS/windows/GUI solution, but as long as it meets the above criteria I would also be interested in other options

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try [dupeGuru](https://dupeguru.voltaicideas.net/).

It can compare 2 folders (A & B).
Set folder A as Reference.
Once all duplicates are found, you can select and delete duplicates all in folder B.

It also has a version called [dupeGuru Picture Edition](https://www.hardcoded.net/dupeguru_pe/).
It claims "Not only can dupeGuru PE find exact matches, but it can also find duplicates among pictures of different kind (PNG, JPG, GIF etc..) and quality."
This could help with your thumbnail scenario. (I have not use this feature before.)

It is [FLOSS](https://github.com/arsenetar/dupeguru/blob/master/LICENSE)/Windows(and macOS, Linux)/GUI

Hope this helps you.

Comment: This works, but it does require me to select the reference folder ahead of time - my scenario is more along the lines of I have duplicates that are sometimes sorted by date, sometimes by event, and sometimes exist in both - I have many dates and many events, so this still a bit tedious - nevertheless, it does answer the question as I wrote it, so thanks!